# Deploy Maven project with Spring+Hibernate to Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, tomcat, maven

I have created a Spring 3 + Hibernate project using Maven in Eclipse. How can I deploy my project to a Tomcat server using Maven.

Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven + Tomcat hot deploy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749500/maven-tomcat-hot-deploy)

Comment: You can use cargo, see here for details: http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.nl/2012/07/how-to-deploy-war-to-tomcat-7-during.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding to what `@Sean Patrick Floyd` and `@Michael Borgwardt` had already suggested, If you are using Eclipse, you can also follow this to generate your `.war` file.

I assume the project is Maven enabled, Else:

> - Right click on your project -> Select Maven -> Select Enable Dependency Management.

**To generate the *.war*:**

> - Right click on your project -> Select Run As -> Select Maven Package.

This will generate a war file into *target* directory located in your project.

**To deploy to Tomcat:**

> - Copy the generated war file to your webapps directory in Tomcat.

Answer (score 8):

If you add the [Tomcat Maven plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html), all you have to do is

```
mvn tomcat:deploy
```

(after adding the server to your Maven configuration)

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough:

On the command line, run

```
mvn clean install
```

or

```
mvn clean package
```

Upload the resulting war file to Tomcat via the [Tomcat Manager Interface](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html).

You'll find the war file at `${basedir}/target/${artifactId}-${version}.war`

Answer (score 1):

Use tomcat maven plugin:

http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you exactly want to do. If you want to do some integration tests, and need therefore to deploy the project in the server, you can also use [maven cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Michael, you should using [Tomcat Maven plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html)

First, adding those configures in you pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
    <configuration>
        <server>local_tomcat</server>
        <url>http://hostname:port/manager/html</url>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
</plugins>
```

Then, you can deploy your web site with one maven command:

```
mvn tomcat7:deploy
```

If you need to undeploy the old deployment first, you can using :

```
http://user:password@hostname:port/manager/text/undeploy?path=/your-web-site-path
```

There is slight difference if you are using old version tomcat. You should refer [Tomcat Maven plugin doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Apache Cargo, which is more general than the Tomcat Maven plugin.

Here is an answer to a related question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10936575/1017787

Answer (score 0):

You can create war file of project using maven. Then you can deploy it in the webapps folder of your tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You must be edit server.xml in your workspace:

```
<Server>
<Service>
    <Engine>
        <Host>
            <Context path="/<myproject>" docBase="<myproject>">
                <Resources className="org.apache.naming.resources.VirtualDirContext"
                    extraResourcePaths="/../<workspace>/<myproject>/src/main/webapp" />
                <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader"
                    virtualClasspath="/../<workspace>/<myproject>/target/classes;/Users/<myuser>/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.15/log4j-1.2.15.jar" />
                <JarScanner scanAllDirectories="true" />
            </Context>
        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

Because, the project structure generate by maven is different. It work with appfuse web application. Also you must be run "mvn tomcat7:deploy"